# Performances issue when using multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two functions which does the same thing - out of two sorted arrays **A** and **B**, return third array **C** with all numbers above median. I had to perform a benchmark for the two functions to see who is better, and then add to the first one threads and check again.

The first function was faster. When i tried to use multiple threads(in the first) i realized that performance was down when i used few threads(for example 4) and was better when i used single thread(i split the work equally between all four threads). At first i though it's related to higher cache miss issue(due to multiple threads), so i tried to set arrays to bigger sizes(millions) and it still happened.

First function

```
public static int[] bigThanMedianAlgo(int []a, int []b)
{
    int [] ans = new int[a.length];
    int num_threads = 4;
    Thread [] threads = new Thread[num_threads];

    long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
        threads[i] = new WorkerThread(a,b,ans, (ans.length/num_threads)*i, (ans.length/num_threads)*(i+1));
        threads[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
        try {
            threads[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long estimated_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
    System.out.println("Run time: worker threads " + estimated_time + "ms");

    return ans;
}
```

Second function

```
public static int[] bigThanMedianMerge(int[]a, int[] b)
{
    int [] ans = new int[a.length];

    long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i = a.length-1, j = b.length-1, r = 0; r < ans.length; r++)
    {
        if(a[i] > b[j])
        {
            ans[r] = a[i--];
        }
        else
        {
            ans[r] = b[j--];
        }
    }

    long estimated_time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;

    System.out.println("Run time: Regular merge " + estimated_time + "ms");
    return ans;
}
```

run method of WorkerThread:

```
public void run()
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) 
    {
        c[i] = Math.max(a[i], b[a.length - i - 1]);
    }
}
```

These are the result for array in size of 15 million items and 4 threads:
Run time: Regular merge 63ms
Run time: worker threads 24ms

These are the result for array in size of 15 million items and 1 thread:
Run time: Regular merge 63ms
Run time: worker threads 17ms

The only thing i changed between executions is the variable **num_threads**.
My computer has Intel i5-8400 CPU(6 cores) and i expected 4 threads will gain a better performances.

Can anyone suggest what might be the reason for that issue ? I can supply further information if needed.